# Подскажите правильно ли я работаю с геолокацией и разрешениями

Tags: java, android, геолокация, permissions

При первом запуске все работает хорошо. Если разрешаешь показывает координаты, если нет то приложения закрывается. Но если разрешил и потом повторно зашел в приложения то не показывает координаты

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private double latitude, longtitude;

    TextView textView;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        checkPermission();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            finish();
        } else {
            getLocation();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLocation(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        onLocationChanged(location);

        textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "\n" + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void checkPermission(){
        int FineLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int CoarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(FineLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && CoarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);

            } else{

            }
        } else{

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("GPS disable!");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want enable GPS?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //start settings window when user can enable GPS
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //close AlertDialog
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog enableGps = builder.create();
        enableGps.show();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде ничего не происходит, если разрешения уже выданы. Вызовите `getLocation();` из обоих `else`  в методе `checkPermission`

Comment: вызвал getLocation(); в методе onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите сказать своим комментарием. Наверное то, что мой ответ вам помог?

Comment: Сделал так как вы говорили, теперь приложения вылетает при запуске. Еще раз проверил и оказалось что оно вылетает если выключен GPS, если включен то все работает. Но тогда почему не работает onProviderDisabled()

Comment: Попробуйте вот так проверять включен ли GPS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21600326/3212712